# Async document download in browser

Tags: html, ajax, pdf

We have a web app with html pages 1>2>3

Page 2 has a link to download a pdf - I've used an anchor tag in the form to do this. The response is of type application/pdf. If I wait on page 2 my pdf eventually shows as downloaded, however I want to be able to move to page 3 with the pdf download happening asynchronously...

I can get the server to do it but as soon as I request page 3 the browser (Chrome) shows the GET request (for the pdf) as status: (canceled) :-(

I've tried both HTTP Request and AJAX Request (type: document and xhr) any suggestions?

So far I can only get it to work when the request is in a new tab  - but that's not what I want as the pdf is downloaded and not opened in the new tab.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution to my problem was to get access to the HttpServletResponse (server side), set the header content type ("application/pdf") and disposition ("attachment;filename='...'") and flush the outputStream.

This must happen ahead of writing the PDF byte array to the outputStream.

The above allowed the browser to show my PDF download as 'started' and I could then navigate away from that page while the download continued.

Answer (score 0):

If your app is `SPA`, you can create an `iframe` and set `src` attribute with the download url.

If it is not `SPA`, and you used `anchor <a>` tag then use `target="_blank"` attribute to download it from a new window in which case, new tab will open and starting the download and the tab will be closed by letting the download happened in the background so that you can change anything on the main page.

Comment: Main issue with target _blank is that it's a bad user experience. As no doc opens in the new tab the customer shouldn't be taken away from their current page. Our app's  not SPA unfortunately

Comment: Better try the iframe approach stated above for `SPA` and see if it helps. On click event of the anchor tag, create iframe and append it to `body` tag . I haven't used this for non `SPA` pages. But it would be better to give a try.

Comment: Will certainly give it a go but suspect that on page 2>3 transition then page 3 Dom will replace the old Dom incl. body and iframe. Any open request assoc. with page 2 iframe will be cancelled...

Comment: Yeah, please give a try.

Comment: No joy. Iframe request is cancelled when the new page is requested

Answer (score 0):

If you want to download rather than show the pdf, I'd look into getting the server setting the http response header

`Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="yourname.pdf"`

so the browser should suggest "save as" and open a dialog to choose the save location - the download will usually continue running when navigating away from the page where the download was initiated.

I'm sorry I have no idea if you can achieve this purely on the browser side.

Comment: I'm doing as you suggest but I need async - meaning the response with the attachment comes after user has navigated away from the page which originated the PDF request. Sync works fine

Comment: I see, you mean before the response starts to arrive (because it takes long) the user navigates away

Comment: Exactly - in Chrome when this happens the PDF request status is 'cancelled'